# Options for suppressing "comparison is always false due to limited range of data type" warning

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

Given some code like :

```
unsigned short val;
//<some unimportant code that sets val>

if(val>65535) val=65535;
```

How can we disable the "comparison is always false due to limited range of data type" warning from gcc?

This is using GCC 4.1.2, and so doesn't have the `#pragma GCC diagnostics` construct.
I can't find a -W option to turn it off either.

I have tried doing a cast of val:

```
if(((long)val)>65535); val=65535
```

But it seems GCC is clever enough to still give the warning.

The compiler flags are -Wall, and that is it. No -Wextra.

I don't really want to remove the check - short might be 16-bits on this target, but doesn't mean it has to be. I am happy to write the check a different way though.

I want to turn -Werror on, so this warning has to go.

**EDIT 1**
Unimportant code not so unimportant:

```
unsigned short val;
float dbValue; (actually function parameter)
val= ((unsigned short) dbValue) & 0xffff);
if(val>65535) val=65535;
```

So if size of short changes, we will get overflow, and in anycase the range check becomes pointless anyway, and can be deleted, or more to the point applied to the float value instead.

**EDIT 2**
Whilst the answers so far have helped improve the code, it would still be useful to know if there is any means to disable this warning in gcc 4.1.2 - which is what the question was.

It seems it can be done in recent releases using -Wno-type-limits

Comment: So you want a saturating 16-bit unsigned int?

Comment: Does this check ((val-65535)>0) help?

Comment: Why do you want to disable the warning? It tells you that your test is useless as is. If you want to detect overflow, you must do so before the fact, i.e. you must enforce this in the code you deemed unimportant.

Comment: @EOF possibly. That seems to be the intent. Its not my code, i am just on a warnings crusade.

Comment: @MOehm: You don't *have to* check before the overflow, because `unsigned` overflow **is defined** to be 2's complement in C. It's `signed` that triggers UB.

Comment: There seems the problem with the premise of this question. Can `val` have values above 65535 before entering the condition? If it can, then `unsigned short` is wrong choice for type. Otherwise you will have different behaviour on 16-bit (wraps around) and 32-bit (limits) `short` .

Comment: @MOehm It is useless given the current compiler and target, but this same code might need to run in the near future on a target that does not have a 16 bit short.

Comment: @EOF: Yes, but how do you tell whether an unsigned integer is the result of a calculation with overflow or not?

Comment: Wow, this seems to be causing more debate than expected!

Comment: _It is useless given the current compiler and target_ I wrote "as is". But if you target platforms with big shorts, the behaviour will be different on the two platforms. Say the unimportant code yields the unoverflowed result of 65538. The 16-bit-short code will have 2, the big-short code will have 65535 as result.

Comment: Doesn't `dbValue && 0xffff` guarantee that the result is <= 65535 - no matter what size short is?

Comment: `if(val >= 65535) val = 65535;` would silence the compiler.

Comment: @Arkadiy yes, it does. I hadnt spotted that before the question edit, as it was hidden inside some macros. However, the question of how you silence the compiler is still valid. Just perhaps not for a valid reason :-) I like the suggestions of using USHRT_MAX as a check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory there is no answer to your question: if what you intend to write is a no-op (on the particular architecture being targeted) for all possible values of `val` the code can be reached with, then the compiler can warn that it is a no-op for all…

In practice, comparing `(val + 0)` instead of `val` may be enough to let the compiler produce the same code as it did with your original version and at the same time shut up about it.

I would recommend you write

```
#include <limits.h>
…
#if USHRT_MAX > 65535
if(val>65535) val=65535;
#endif
```

I feel that if you were to use it without comment, it makes the intention clearer than any convoluted trick.

Comment: This is the sort of thing i was hoping for, although i was thinking of UINT16_MAX, which obviously wouldn't help.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of conditional compilation:

```
#include <limits.h>

unsigned short val;

#if USHRT_MAX > 65535
  if(val>65535) val=65535;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

`val` was declared as an `unsigned short`, which *usually* (see note) means 16-bit unsigned (0 - 65535), so your test can never be true, because `val` can never be more than 2^16-1 (65535) *with this compiler, and with this target architecture*.

Casting it as a `long` won't change anything.  You may want to declare `val` as `unsigned long` though.

**EDIT**

*note*: as rightly implied in the comments section, the exact width of `short` and `int` types depend on both the compiler and the target architecture.  Wikipedia has a section on [basic C data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types) that covers the question in greater details.

Comment: Who says `unsigned short` has to be 16 bit exactly?

Comment: `unsigned int` might also be 16-bits, so I don't see how this helps.

Comment: @EOF: obviously his compiler does.  But yeah, fair enough.

Comment: @xbug This compiler does. But this same codebase needs to run on many different targets.

Comment: @mjs: then be explicit about it, and declare `val` as `uint16_t`.

Comment: I considered that, and might well do so in the future. But this codebase doesn't use those types at all. If i had written it though.......

Comment: Edited to reflect the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Using the min macro :

```
#define min(x, y)   (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))
val=min(val,65535);
```

gets rid of the warning. So we can also use the same implementation directly

```
val=(val)<(65535)? val: 65535;
```

The trick here is that while a 16 bit integer cannot be greater than 65535, it can be 65535, and the check in this version is "is it lower than 65535

Comment: This still doesn't address the fact that code will work differently on different `short` size.

Comment: @user694733 True, although the size is only likely to get larger, in which case the check still holds

Comment: Yes, for larger sizes, but as mentioned in question comments for 16-bits it doesn't. For `val = 65538` you get `val == 2`, not 65535. If overflow is acceptable, then you would be better off with `val &= 0xFFFF`. Then you would at least get consistent behaviour between platforms.

Comment: Hmmm... Good point. Turns out the <unimportant code> was important. See question edit

Comment: Nothing to add, if you meant to write `val = ((unsigned short) dbValue) & 0xffff;` (with one `&`).